# cv2 show video stream & add overlay after another function finishes

Tags: python, opencv

I am current working on a real time face detection project.

What I have done is that I capture the frame using cv2, do detection and then show result using cv2.imshow(), which result in a low fps.

I want a high fps video showing on the screen without lag and a low fps detection bounding box overlay.

Is there a solution to show the real time video stream (with the last detection result bounding box), and once a new detection is finished, show the new bounding box and the background was not delayed by the detection function.

Any help is appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A common approach would be to create a flag that allows the detection algorithim to only run once every couple of frames and save the predicted reigons of interest to a list, whilst creating bounding boxes for every frame.

So for example you have a face detection algorithim, process every 15th frame to detect faces, but in every frame create a bounding box from the predictions. Even though the predictions get updated every 15 frames.

Another approach could be to add an object tracking layer. Run your heavy algorithim to find the ROIs and then use the object tracking library to hold on to them till the next time it runs the detection algorithim.

Hope this made sense.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, Rupaksh:)

I have considered the first approach myself, the problem is the processing time of the detection algorithm can fluctuate, leading to the fps may vary from 15fps to 30fps depending on how many faces are in the frame. If I use the first approach, I may have to set the rate to every 15 frames, which is the lowest performance.

Comment: My ideal solution is to run two different thread, the first one simply just show the video stream from the camera, the second one will do the detect and once a result is acquired, add the bounding box as a overlay to the video stream. But I don't know how to implement it. And could you elaborate your second approach? Thanks!

Comment: I'm fairly new to all of this. When you say you're considering threading, how would you go about appending the new boxes onto the frame? Maybe this is is a really basic question but I don't have any experience with threading.

Comment: Okay so the second approach is something I found here - https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/07/23/simple-object-tracking-with-opencv/

I couldn't really get it to work for myself, but maybe you'll have better luck. Cheers! Let me know how it goes.

Comment: I've managed to do it by using threading, mutex and global variable. I created some global variables that are shared during two functions. The first function read the frame from the camera and then check global variable bounding box, if it is not None, add the bounding box to the frame, and then print the frame. The second function get the global variable frame (obtained by the first function), do detection and recognition and modify global variables bounding box and identity. I add mutex to operations related to bounding box and identity variable in case there is a crash.

Comment: Thank you for your ideas and inspiration:)

Comment: Interesting approach! Thanks a lot for helping me out. Would you mind pointing me in the right direction to study multi threading and mutex in python. I don't have a CS background, so my knowledge is really rough around the edges in these spaces.

Comment: I'm also kinda new to multithreading. What I have learned is just some basic knowledge and concept of multithreading and mutex. If you are entirely new to this field, I would suggest spend some time getting familiar with the basic concepts. Then if you want to implement the concepts, you might firstly decide what language you want to use because implementation in different languages can be completely different. Then you just search online about how to implement some functionality, do the coding and tackle one problem after another. Wish you good luck in this field:)